# How do I draw an image loaded from the page in a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas, load

I have a html page like this:

```
<html> 
    <body>
          (1)<canvas id="cs"></canvas>
          (2)<img src="/image.png" id="img"/> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

I would like to know how I could load and display the image (2) in the canvas (1) (with drawImage function).
I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
var img = $("#img");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to edit the title to say [solved].  Simply check the box of whichever answer was most useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ensure that your image has loaded first. Try wrapping your drawImage call in a ready statment and make certain you are setting up your canvas object first.

```
$().ready(function(){
   var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("img"),0,0);

})
```

If you haven't already found it here is a nice tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Comment: to make it work with the $("#img") use var img = $("#img").get(0); The reason your code didn't work is because jquery returns an array of elements and you have to get the first one to use in other javascript methods

Answer (score 0):

Is that all of your code?

You need to set up the canvas first:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('cs').getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src=document.getElementById('img').src;
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

Something like that...

Here's an example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vTYqS/

Note that the first picture gets cut off because of the default canvas size.  Depending on the image you plan to copy, you may need to resize your canvas like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vTYqS/1/

Comment: no, it's not all code.
it works with document.getElementById("img") rather than $("#img");
thanks !

Comment: No reason to duplicate the image. You can get rid of line 3 and change 4 to `ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('img'),0,0)` after ensuring the image has loaded.

Comment: you're right, and there are probably 20 other ways to do it too-- but using new Image() doesn't actually download a new image, so you're not saving any bandwidth. it just seemed kind of harsh to downvote, but they're your votes. thanks for responding.